# Getting an SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my application, I have a copy of an SQLite database in my assets folder. As far as I know, it's working fine. When my application installs for the first time in my emulator, I get an error like so:

> ```
> Failed to open the database. Closing it.
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
> E/SQLiteDatabase(7516): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
> E/SQLiteDatabase(29308):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
> E/SQLiteDatabase(29308):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
> E/SQLiteDatabase(29308):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:962) 
> E/SQLiteDatabase(29308):  at com.guayama.database.URLDatabaseHelper.checkDBExists(URLDatabaseHelper.java:86) 
> E/SQLiteDatabase(29308):  at com.guayama.database.URLDatabaseHelper.createURLDB(URLDatabaseHelper.java:54)
> E/SQLiteDatabase(29308):  at com.guayama.database.URLDatabaseHelper.<init>(URLDatabaseHelper.java:38)
> ```

Here is my initial code to open the database:

```
 SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
```

Here is another method that I tried:

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

I also tried using this:

```
 SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: see this post maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151147/failed-to-open-database-in-android-app

Comment: already i tried this one

Comment: Hi Chiru ,Have you copied your database ? can we see that part of the code where you copy the db from path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always follow below step to copy my database from assets folder:

```
  private void copyDatabase() throws IOException{

        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String dbCreatePath = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbCreatePath);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = inputStream.read(buffer))>0){
            outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
}
```

Once it is copied i will check like below :

```
  private boolean checkDatabase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String dbPath = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,     
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    if(checkDB!=null){
        checkDB.close();}
    return checkDB != null ? true:false;

}
```

Comment: i got this exception after adding ur code SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file

Comment: please check it once i have added log

Comment: Did you tried calling createDatabase() before openDatabase(). like this: URLDatabaseHelper  dbHelper = new URLDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
dbHelper.createDatabase();
     
dbHelper.openDatabase();

Comment: i got error on  checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath,null,     
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

Comment: yes, i got the same error on checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath,null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

and my db path is "/data/data/<package name>/databases/db.s3db"

Comment: im getting this error especially in Android honeycomb, in other versions it works perfect.

Comment: @fargath : Its better you post your own question if you are facing any problems.

Comment: Im having the same problem which described above, so i don want to create a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem, the difference being that the database works in my Eclipse Nexus 7 emulator but not on the Nexus 7 itself. I downloaded Questoid to be able to see what's in my database after I copy it from the assets folder but for some time the database did not even show up in File Explorer. I kept on doing the copy and finally it showed up. Having gone through the same process several times, I have not yet been able to figure out what is the common denominator, but repetition seems to be the key in my case. Now I still have to figure out why my Nexus 7 itself can't open the database when I install the app on the device. I experience the same exception, but only on the device itself.