# SQLite Exception to handle locked databases

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am working with SQLite database files, and I notice that when database file is in use, I see that it prints "SQLite error: database is locked". I have tried using SQLiteException with try.catch, but that does not work. What I want to know, is, how can I catch the error before it repeats, and display a message to the user? In other words, what I want to do is set the default retries\timeout for the connection, so that my application does not appear to be unresponsive while it retries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this, simply rename the file and copy it back to it's original name and location.

```
mv mydata.db temp.db
cp temp.db mydata.db
```

Your question is similar to the query ["How do I unlock a SQLite database?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database) 
I think the answers provided for this question will help you to resolve your issue very easily.