# Locked sqlite IN THE WHOLE SYSTEM

Tags: linux, sqlite, debian, nfs

i got a big problem in my system. Some how, the entire sqlite sistem become locked. I am not talking about a single database, i am talking about every database in the system.

```
ladb08@newcastle:~$ touch new.sqlite3
ladb08@newcastle:~$ sqlite3 new.sqlite3 
SQLite version 3.7.3
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
Error: database is locked
sqlite>
```

Even firefox cant open properly because of the same problem. 
I got no idea of why this happened.
This server is a debian server, and it is used by my team to develop some site with rails. We centralize the stuff in a external git repo so everyone work with his own user, and with his own copy of the stuff.

Another test:

```
ladb08@newcastle:~/agendador/db$ lsof test.sqlite3 
ladb08@newcastle:~/agendador/db$ fuser test.sqlite3 
ladb08@newcastle:~/agendador/db$ strace -e fcntl sqlite3 test.sqlite3 .tables
fcntl(3, F_GETFD) = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
fcntl(4, F_GETFD) = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fcntl(3, F_SETLK, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=1073741824, len=1}) = -1 ENOLCK (No locks available)
Error: database is locked
```

No one is using the database. And the same occurs to empty new ones.

===========================================================================

More info:

```
root@newcastle:~# cd /home/ladb08/agendador/db/            
root@newcastle:/home/ladb08/agendador/db# sqlite3 test.sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.3
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
Error: database is locked
sqlite> .exit
```

The problem, as usual.

```
root@newcastle:~# cd /root           
root@newcastle:~# cp /home/ladb08/agendador/db/test.sqlite3 ./
root@newcastle:~# sqlite3 test.sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.3
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
agendamentos              prefeituras               tipo_atendimentos      
bloqueios                 profissionais             tipo_situacoes         
cidadaos                  schema_migrations         tmibges                
escalas                   tcbos                     tufibges               
orgaos                    tconselhos             
orgaos_tipo_atendimentos  tipo_acoes
```

Outside the nfs partition, no problem with the same file.

```
root@newcastle:~# mount
(...)
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
urquell.home2:/home2/home-newcastle on /home type nfs (rw,v3,addr=10.17.116.3)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I unlock a SQLite database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database)

Comment: I looked that post.
We tried to reboot the system, but it didn't solve anything.
fuser don't say anything about anyone using the file.

Comment: What is the output of `strace -e fcntl sqlite3 test.sqlite3 .tables`?

Comment: ladb08@newcastle:~/agendador/db$ strace -e fcntl sqlite3 

test.sqlite3 .tables

fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0

fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0

fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)

fcntl(3, F_SETLK, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=1073741824, len=1}) = -1 ENOLCK (No locks available)

Error: database is locked`

@CL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code `ENOLCK` is returned when the kernel runs out of memory for locks (unlikely in your case) or when a locking operation over a remote file system like NFS failed.

Apparently, your file server is configured to not support file locking.
(Whether that would be a good idea [is debatable](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html).)

Comment: I have forgot about this. This server is a virtual server, and the disk is a nfs disk.

Comment: Thanx to this, i notice that the problem IS related to NFS.