# Problems with sessions in django...what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I am watching the video tutorial
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_dDY7TvJ4E&list=PLxxA5z-8B2xk4szCgFmgonNcCboyNneMD And at the moment my code gets a value from the url (the language) and passes it into the language view function which takes the value and sets it as a session called "lang". It also makes a cookie called "lang". These are the relevant files:

http://pastebin.com/A6gb2em6

(sorry i had problems putting the code on here, it would not let me submit for some reason.)

the error i am getting is:
DatabaseError: database is locked

I have no idea what this means and do not understand why the database has any relevance to the session. It all worked until i added the session system, as in, the cookies would set correctly. 
Any ideas how to fix this? If you need any other information please ask!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `sqllite` for your database?

Comment: yea i am. Is it necessary to change?

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by:
Type: $ fuser (database name)  (from the same location as your database).

It gives:

database name: XYZ
(XYZ is a result you get from fuser)

Then type:

kill -9 ABCD

example:

$ fuser blog.sqlite

blog: 1234

$ kill -9 1234

Hope it helps.