# SQLite Database locked in sqlite admin

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite

I need help with an SQLite process. It crashed while doing a create query and as a result now will not add a anything to the database as it is "locked"; how can I unlock it?

Other questions answers I don't understand. I need simple as possible please. The database it called "KCD.s3db" I'm working in vb.net.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database

Comment: As i stated in my question that these didn't work or i don't understand how to do them.

Comment: Another possibility is that the database still has the process attached to it. Did you try rebooting?

Comment: Yeah rebooted, tried from different computer, rebooted new computer, replaced database file with a back up. It just won't let me add or update! It's really important course work! I have a backup from 2 days ago but i might lose all the work i did yesterday! :(

Comment: Let's get this straight: (1) the sqlite client says it is locked (post an image), but you can add data to it, (2) your vb gives an error when you add or update, (3) the symptom is the same whether the file is on one machine or another and all symptoms persist through rebooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically i forgot to dispose of a query before i ran another query and this caused a reserved lock to be place on the database. Simple fix was to dispose sql command.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the database to a different location and opening it. Also see [How do I unlock a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database)

Comment: It opens and writes in the SQL client perfectly! It's when i am trying to write from vb.net program thats the problem!

Comment: So the database is not locked in the sqlite client? But the error that it is locked comes from vb.net?

Comment: It states at the bottom of the SQL client that it is locked but still lets me add to it via the client itself!