# Django + Sqlite: database is locked

Tags: django, sqlite

After a electrical failure my network database having problems

I open my login page by running the program but after, the username and password are no longer recognized

I get the error

```
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Value Exception: database is locked
```

and my function :

```py
def main_page(request):
    state = ""
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

The problem comes from this line : user =....

How can I fix this ?

Comment: This is not a Django problem. This is a Sqlite problem. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database)

Comment: For me the problem was NFS and found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366752/8826047

Answer (score 9):

From [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#database-is-locked-errors):

> SQLite is meant to be a lightweight database, and thus can’t support a
>   high level of concurrency. OperationalError: database is locked errors
>   indicate that your application is experiencing more concurrency than
>   sqlite can handle in default configuration. This error means that one
>   thread or process has an exclusive lock on the database connection and
>   another thread timed out waiting for the lock the be released.
>
> Python’s SQLite wrapper has a default timeout value that determines
>   how long the second thread is allowed to wait on the lock before it
>   times out and raises the OperationalError: database is locked error.
>
> If you’re getting this error, you can solve it by:
>
> - Switching to another database backend. At a certain point SQLite becomes too “lite” for real-world applications, and these sorts of
>     concurrency errors indicate you’ve reached that point.
> - Rewriting your code to reduce concurrency and ensure that database transactions are short-lived.
> - Increase the default timeout value by setting the timeout database option

Comment: I have just a question. Could you tell me why, before this electric breakdown, It worked perfectly...with sqlite

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database) would answer your question as @vape suggested above.