# how to Query into sqlite3 in golang?

Tags: sqlite, go

My table function

```
func createTransactionTable(db *sql.DB) {
    transaction := `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Transaction_history(
        "rollno" INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        "isReward" INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        "transfered_to" INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        "transfered_amount" INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        "redeems" INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        "date" TEXT NOT NULL
        );`
    statement, err := db.Prepare(transaction)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    statement.Exec()
    fmt.Println("trasaction  table created")
}
```

query function

```
count, err := db.Exec(`SELECT count(isReward) from Transaction_history WHERE rollno = ? AND isReward = ?`, rollno, 1)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if count != 0 {
    return true
}
return false
```

I am trying to find the no of rows of in my table where isReward = 1 and rollno is as specified of our choice but is giving and i dont know how to achieve, i know it is a very basic but literally searched but didn't get anything that will fit my need, so need help

Comment: I don't understand that this question is pretty clear what i am asking, still people instead  of helping dislike your  question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Tx.Exec):

> Exec executes a query that doesn't return rows. For example: an INSERT and UPDATE.

Try `Query` instead. I didn't test this against your dataset (obviously) but hopefully it gives you some good direction. Also you should properly handler errors.

```
type row struct {
    Count int `json:"count"`
}
response, _ := db.Query("SELECT count(isReward) as count from Transaction_history WHERE rollno = ? AND isReward = ?", rollno, 1)
var rows []row
_ = response.Scan(&rows)
count := rows[0].Count
```

If you're getting a database lock error, make sure you're not trying to query SQLite concurrently. You can create a global mutex, and make sure that every query against the database acquires the lock.

```
var m sync.Mutex

func createTransactionTable(...) {
    m.Lock()
    defer m.Unlock()
    // Perform your query here
}
```

Comment: Also i am facing database lock error , i had searched that mutex can solve this can you like how can i apply mutexes

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/274) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479071/sqlite3-error-database-is-locked-in-golang). Also see my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier if you use Driver like [this](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3)

```
sqliteDatabase, _ := sql.Open
    ("sqlite3", "./sqlite-database.db") // Open the created SQLite File
    defer sqliteDatabase.Close() // Defer Closing the database
    createTable(sqliteDatabase) // Create Database Tables

        // INSERT RECORDS
    insertStudent(sqliteDatabase, "0001", "Liana Kim", "Bachelor")

// and InsertStudent func like this

createStudentTableSQL := `CREATE TABLE student (
        "idStudent" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,     
        "code" TEXT,
        "name" TEXT,
        "program" TEXT      
      );` 

    log.Println("Create student table...")
    statement, err := db.Prepare(createStudentTableSQL) // Prepare SQL Statement
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    statement.Exec() // Execute SQL Statements
    log.Println("student table created")
```

You can use methods like this