# sqlite3 - access to mounted db file, database is locked

Tags: linux, database, sqlite

I need to access db file, which is mounted  via mount -t cifs on linux to windows file system.
I also mounted my computer to this windows file system.
If I want to write something to this database from my computer, it works. No problem.
But when I want to write something to this database from linux machine, it always sais that database is locked. I can't figure it out.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Note: Of course my mount from linux have RW permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unlock a SQLite database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 11):

Add the option `nobrl` to your mount command.