# sqlite3 c++ function: INSERT statement not executed when it comes as an argument

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am implementing a function that receives any SQL statement and then executes it.

```
void dbExec(std::string str, bool vertical)
{
   sqlite3 *db; // Create db object
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;
   const char *sql = str.c_str(); // Convert string to char
   sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL; // SQL statement

   /* Open Database */
   rc = sqlite3_open("db/survey.db",&db);
   if (rc)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "DBOPEN_ERR: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
   }

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL); // Prepare statement

   if (rc != SQLITE_OK )
   { // Check error
      fprintf(stderr, "DB error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   }

   int cols = sqlite3_column_count(stmt); // Number of columns
   const char *data = NULL; // data char pointer

   if (vertical)
   {
      sqlite3_step( stmt );
      for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
      {
         // Print column name and info
         data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, i );
         std::cout << std::setw(20) << sqlite3_column_name(stmt,i)
                   << std::setw(30) << (data ? data : "[NULL]" );
         printf("\n");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
      {
         // Print column name
         std::cout << std::setw(15) << sqlite3_column_name(stmt,i);
      }
      printf("\n");

      while ( sqlite3_step( stmt ) == SQLITE_ROW )
      {
         // print each row
         for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
         {
            data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, i );
            std::cout << std::setw(15) << (data ? data : "[NULL]" );
         }
         printf("\n");
      }
   }

   /* Close Database */
   sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

When the `str` argument is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

it works perfect. If the `str` argument is:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1) VALUES(100)
```

it doesn't work.

However, if inside of the function I add the following line:

```
str = "INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1) VALUES(100)";
```

it works perfect. I tried many things but I still can't figure out what's going on... Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:
The function `dbExec` is being called in this way:

```
void addBorehole()
{
   std::string statement;
   statement = "INSERT INTO BOREHOLE (TOTAL_DEPTH) VALUES (45)";

   dbExec(statement, false);
}
```

Comment: *"When I input in str..."* - there is no such "input" operation in this post. And considering blatantly overruling that operation and hard-coding the "same" string within your function functions correctly, perhaps your real problem lays in the code you chose *not* to post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just updated the question with the full code.

Comment: There are lots of errors in this code, but none of them should prevent the INSERT from executing. And you have not shown the full code; provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just a hint: Pass a `std::string` as `const std::string&` to avoid copying the whole string and just pass a reference. This doesn't solve your problem but is best practice. Could you also provide the call to `dbExec`?.

Comment: @AndreKampling thanks for the hint. I added the call to dbExec

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: Also you mixed using `printf` and `std::cout`, that is a bad practice because you are mixing C and C++. Just use `std::cout`, if you want a new line like you do with printf you can do the following: `std::cout << std::endl;`.

Comment: @CL. with 'doesn't work' I mean that it is not inserting a new record in the table.

Comment: @AndreKampling thanks for your comments, I am not a software engineer and I am learning how to code by myself to make software for my job, so any comments and hints are welcome.

Comment: You're welcome! So what does the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` return as error code? [These](https://sqlite.org/rescode.html) are the error codes that are possible.

Comment: @AndreKampling no error is printed when SQLITE_OK is checked. It behaves as if the SQL statement was executed successfully. I tried changing the permissions in the db and running as root because I thought it was a problem with the permissions but still didn't work.

Comment: The actual statement evaluation is done at `sqlite3_step( stmt );`. You don't check the return code of that. Please also check that and tell us about that.

Comment: @AndreKampling well, I found that sqlite3_step( stmt ) == SQLITE_BUSY, but this is the only process opening the database :/ any ideas?

Comment: OK! found the answer: put sqlite3_finalize( stmt ); before closing the database. Now it's working as expected. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the database is busy (`SQLITE_BUSY`). The [documentation](https://sqlite.org/rescode.html) sais:

> [...] SQLITE_BUSY indicates a conflict with a separate database connection, probably in a separate process [...]

So there must be a process that is blocking your database.
To get the process which is blocking the database you can do the following (Copied from the Stack Exchange network).

**[Linux:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database)**

> > $ fuser development.db
>
> This command will show what process is locking the file:
>
> > > development.db: 5430
>
> Just kill the process...
>
> kill -9 5430

**[Windows:](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)**

> PowerShell method:
>
> ```
> IF((Test-Path -Path $FileOrFolderPath) -eq $false) {
>     Write-Warning "File or directory does not exist."       
> }
> Else {
>     $LockingProcess = CMD /C "openfiles /query /fo table | find /I ""$FileOrFolderPath"""
>     Write-Host $LockingProcess
> }
> ```
>
> More details [How to find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-find-out-which-c0d4e60e)

The other method for Windows would be to use the [ProcessExplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was solved by writing the following line before closing the database:

```
sqlite3_finalize( stmt );
```

Info: https://sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html

> If the database connection is associated with unfinalized prepared
>   statements or unfinished sqlite3_backup objects then sqlite3_close()
>   will leave the database connection open and return SQLITE_BUSY.

However, I still didn't get why it worked when I hardcoded the statement inside of the function.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you run the hardcoded version first when there was no database access before, so that the database was not busy. You can test it again with your code.