# Spring Hibernate5 and SQLite database is locked

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sqlite

When I try to save a new istance on the db I get Spring database is locked.
I'm using

```
  <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>asm</groupId>
                            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>asm</groupId>
                            <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
```

And for sqlite dialect

```
    <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.gwenn</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
                    <version>master</version>
                </dependency>
```

Do exist a better dialect for hibernate5 that close the connection after findAll?
Or Some configuration in the xml?
The configurations are:

```
<bean id="emf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.accenture.moparva.datalayer.models" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>

                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">false</prop>
                <prop key="maxActive">1</prop>

            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

The error is:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: error performing isolated work; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: error performing isolated work] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: database is locked
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:859)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.exec(DB.java:142)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.commit(JDBC3Connection.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.d
```

Comment: it could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database