# Error while deploying Shiny app to RStudio Connect

Tags: r, sqlite

While trying to deploy a Shiny app on RStudio Connect I receive the following error:

```
----- Deployment error -----
Error: HTTP 500
GET http://10.80.40.13:3939/__api__/tasks/YUJMyIjVyh3Pm87i?first_status=487

<h1>An error has occurred</h1>

<p id="message">database is locked</p>
```

The server is not under heavy load and currently there are only 5 users and one app on the server.

I tried a few steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database). Killed the process using the db. I then moved `connect.db` to another location and then copied it back to `/var/lib/rstudio-connect/db/`. After this step I could not even login to RStudio Connect. I did an integrity check on `connect.db` and found it to be ok butt still no joy. Next, I restored the db to a previous version. I am able to login now but while deploying the Shiny app, still receiving the same error.

The app I am trying to deploy has already been successfully deployed on the server. What I am trying to deploy now is a modified version of the same app, with the only change being an addition of a `pickerInput()`.

Comment: I suspect this is not enough information to be able to help (log files might be telling). Tour tags [tag:shiny] and [tag:rstudio-server] are not appropriate, as this it not a shiny problem, and RSP is a different product completely from RSC. If you don't get any good replies here on SO, you may have better luck browsing and perhaps asking at https://community.rstudio.com/.

Comment: @r2evans thanks, have posted this at rstudio community too, pending approval. Removed the tags as suggested.

Comment: The question has been asked and answered [on RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-app-deployment-error-on-rstudio-connect/21958).