# How to fix : "Unable to commit against JDBC Connection" error in hibernate when I update entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to do an update function to update the entity with hibernate.
so I did that :

```
public boolean update(Collecte obj) {
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();  
        transaction = session.beginTransaction(); 

        Collecte oldCollecte = this.find(obj.getId());
        Collecte oldCollecteMerged = (Collecte) session.merge(oldCollecte);
        Collecte objMerged = (Collecte) session.merge(obj);

        oldCollecteMerged.setId(objMerged.getId());
        oldCollecteMerged.setAdresse(objMerged.getAdresse());
        oldCollecteMerged.setAuteur(objMerged.getAuteur());
        oldCollecteMerged.setDate(objMerged.getDate());
        oldCollecteMerged.setEnquete(objMerged.getEnquete());
        oldCollecteMerged.setGmao(objMerged.getGmao());
        oldCollecteMerged.setLocal(objMerged.getLocal());
        oldCollecteMerged.setPce(objMerged.getPce());
        oldCollecteMerged.setReponse(objMerged.getReponse());

        session.merge(oldCollecteMerged);
        transaction.commit();   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But an error triggers at the line "translation.commit()" :

- Unable to commit against JDBC Connection

Edit : 
More exactly, this is the full error message :

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
    at dao.CollecteDAO.update(CollecteDAO.java:77)
    at Controlleur.Ctr_formulaire.actionPerformed(Ctr_formulaire.java:121)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:918)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.exec(DB.java:178)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.commit(SQLiteConnection.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:81)
    ... 40 more
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
    at dao.CollecteDAO.update(CollecteDAO.java:77)
    at Controlleur.Ctr_formulaire.actionPerformed(Ctr_formulaire.java:121)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:918)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.exec(DB.java:178)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.commit(SQLiteConnection.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:81)
    ... 40 more
Hibernate: select enquete0_.id as id1_4_, enquete0_.cloture as cloture2_4_, enquete0_.dateFermeture as dateFerm3_4_, enquete0_.dateOuverture as dateOuve4_4_, enquete0_.user_id as user_id6_4_, enquete0_.titre as titre5_4_ from Enquete enquete0_ where enquete0_.id=?
août 06, 2019 10:24:08 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 5, SQLState: null
août 06, 2019 10:24:08 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.wrapLockException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
    at dao.EnqueteDAO.find(EnqueteDAO.java:106)
    at dao.EnqueteDAO.find(EnqueteDAO.java:1)
    at Controlleur.Ctr_formulaire.actionPerformed(Ctr_formulaire.java:126)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect$3.convert(SQLiteDialect.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1984)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1914)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:918)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:134)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:257)
    at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.<init>(CorePreparedStatement.java:47)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:30)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:19)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC4Connection.java:35)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:241)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    ... 56 more
```

**I tried:**

- Call my update function at the start of my main => in this case the update function works
- Use the "fuser" command in order to see if another process uses my "bd.db" file, but apparently not.
- I have change the LockMode in my query like that :

```
session.createQuery("update Collecte set local=true where id= ?0")
            .setParameter(0, obj.getId())
            .setLockMode("alias", LockMode.WRITE)
            .executeUpdate();
```

```
   => but I have the same error
```

**Maybe**

- Maybe my program does not have the right to change data in my program? (even if my insert function works well)
- It seems to be a kind of conflict? The "merge" has to avoid this kind of error no?
- It's may about the lockMode ?

Comment: Please show your stacktrace

Comment: _"Caused by: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)"_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unlock a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database)

Comment: Why are you using  Collecte oldCollecte = this.find(obj.getId()); outside of transaction bonds?

Comment: @Augusto I'am not sure, I have not find a solution to my problem in this topic

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes I see that, but I don't know how to fix that, can I say to hibernate to unlock my db ?

Comment: @Ermintar yes thanks, it's a mistake I changed that

Comment: I don't normally use sqlite, but as far as I know, depending on the version and the exact compilation options, it may only allow a single connection. Or possibly you have multiple processes open that access the same database.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes I have already read that somewhere, but my HibernateUtil classe give only one instance of session in order to avoid this problem. I try "fuser" commande on "bd.db" and there are only one PID when I start my program (the PID of my program I think)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be resolved by placing the start of the transaction at the top of the method.